# Prove exponential of unbounded differential operator needs not to converge

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $A :C^1([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ be the differential operator such that $A f = f'$. where $D(A) = C^{1}([0,1])\subset C([0,1])$ with sup norm on it.We can check that $A$  is unbounded linear operator.

Prove that series defined on $f\in C^\infty([0,1])$ such that $$S(t) f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{t^k (A^kf)}{k!}$$
This series needs not to converge in $C([0,1])$

I think there is something to do with Taylor series expansion.Is there some example?

Comment: That series isn't even well defined on most $f$, it could only be done on smooth functions, not just $C^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @Alan points out in the comments, the series is not well-defined on $\mathcal C([0,1])$, as the intersection of the domains of the operators $A^k$ is $\mathcal C^\infty([0,1])\subsetneq \mathcal C([0,1])$.*

However, even on smooth functions the series need not converge. Indeed, it is a special case of [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) that for any sequence of real numbers $(r_n)$, there is a smooth function $f \in\mathcal C^\infty([0,1])$ with $A^kf(0) = r_k$. If you choose $r_k = (k!)^2$, then the series $S(t)f$ does not converge in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ *for any* $t\neq 0$.

The series clearly converges for polynomial functions (since it is actually a finite sumn).

For analytic functions, the series might converge for some $t$ and not others. For example, $f(t) = 1/(1+t)$ has $\|A^kf\| = k!$, which means that $S(t)f$ converges in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ for every $|t|<1$ and cannot converge for every $|t|>1$.

---

**Conjecture :**

For an analytic functions $f$, the series $S(t)f$ will converge in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ for $t$ small enough. More precisely, let $\rho_x$ be the convergence radius of the taylor series of $f$ at $x\in[0,1]$. Then, by compacity of $[0,1]$, we know that $\rho = \inf_{x\in[0,1]}\rho_x$ is strictly positive. I think one can prove that $S(t)f$ converges in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ for $|t|<\rho$.

Comment: thank you the conjecture above implies  Borel's lemma does not hold for real analytic function correct?@SolubleFish

Comment: Yes, although it is easy to prove that Borel's lemma does not hold for analytic functions : if $f(t)$ is an analytic function whose Taylor series at $0$ has a convergence radius $>r>0$, then $f^{(n)}(0) = o(r^{-n}n!)$. Therefore, there is no analytic function with $f^{(n)}(0) = (n!)^2$